# Performance between calling function on ngStyle vs directive

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-directive

What is the main difference of

```
<p [ngStyle]="getStyle()"> 
// getStyle returns a string like "color:blue" and some other attributes
```

to

```
<p appStyle [status]="myStatus">
//directive get myStatus as a input and calculate the style of the tag
```

The application that I'm doing maintenance call these functions `getStyle` on `ngStyle` a lot (probably 5k times). I am currently changing the style calculation to directives, because I think its cleaner.

But I don't know how much it will affect performance. How could I measure it?

Another question, is there a document/tutorial/book that explain things like that?

Thanks

Comment: why not use CSS? Can you show the implementation logic of how the style string is calculated?

Comment: I used string in my example, it is not a string. It is a combination of 4 divs that are depeding of a lot of attributes. Based on attributes like product, status, client and etc. So, only CSS could be hard cause the styles colors are stored in enums / database, and it's a long list of them. @Saksham

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function call in property binding must be avoided as much as possible, this is because the function is called on every angular change detection cycle even an unrelated property is changed on the component view. Because of this reason "getStyle()" method bound to [ngStyle] is called many many times [even more than expected].
Your second code approach [directive] one is far better than function one. In the directive approach when your bounded input PROPERTY is changed then only your underlying directive's input property change related code gets executed. Also you can enhance the performance by using ChangeDetectionStrtegy.OnPush [https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/].
Also, Angular pipe should be used in case you are transforming your data from data to presentation. Because pipes are memoized [i.e. Pipe evaluated only if the input is changed].

See the following articles -

https://blog.angularindepth.com/tiny-angular-pipe-to-make-any-function-memoizable-f6c8fa917f2f
https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-pure-and-impure-pipes-and-why-that-matters-999818aa068

Comment: So I think calling 'get' methods have the same problem, right? What is the proper way to use the result a 'get' function to render some data. Thanks

Comment: @RafaelAndrade ultimately get is again a function. And get property call performance depends on what it returns. If it returns some immutable object [not changed object] then angular does not re-render anything. If get returns something changed then it re-render. We can provide a "better" way if we have the code snippet of your getter and template. Bottom line is - Angular re-render if bounded property changes [i.e. reference or the value]

Comment: I will try to create the snippet latter and send it here.