# Angular property binding loop more than should

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In my array pitanje['odgovori'] I have 3 values so it should loop only three, but somehow it loop several times look at picture...So [0,1,2] and loop several times...My goal is to pass that value to changeColor() 
 and compare with other to change chip color base on that

[image]

HTML

```
<ion-chip *ngFor="let odgovor of pitanje['odgovori']; index as i" 
 [color]="changeColor(i)">
     <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon>
     <ion-label>{{ odgovor }}</ion-label>
</ion-chip>
```

TS

```
changeColor(value: number) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: when is changeColor() called? I recommend posting a code snippet where it is called.

Comment: @codeherk look at ion-chip [color] property thank you for effort

Comment: sorry! definitely missed that.

Comment: no problem, this is some nonsense but can't get it this evening..

Comment: A better solution would be to add a color property to your odgovor object instead of using a method to determine the color. Then you can calculate the color beforehand and do something like [color]='odgovor.color'

Comment: i think of that but missed it at start now have to change that array to array of objects in a lot of other places

Comment: Possibly this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56454290/2216584

Comment: Better to fix it and take the time to do it properly if you have the time. Your method is getting called multiple times because of Angular change detection, here is a good article explaining it https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: I just read about that...thank you all for your effort! @andre lombaard

Comment: It's a pleasure, good luck, hope it doesn't take too much time to fix.

Comment: Angular is doing change detection, so your method will be called each time Angular does a change detection tick.

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be to use a pipe for the changeColor function. The pipe will get the i value and its transform function will do what the changecolor function is supposed to do.

The benefit of pipe that it is pure and wont happen again after change detection if it is not related the state that directly change the pipe result.

Another solution is to use lodash-decorators and the memoize decorator.

```
import {memoize} from 'lodash-decorators';

@memoize()
changeColor(value: number) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

This will not enter the function if called with the same values.